# Extract variable names from .txt file with RegEx

Tags: powershell, regex

I want to extract a variable name (e.g. `$00incomplete_frame`) from a text file and place the names in a variable for use in PowerShell.
The source variable names do not contain spaces. A source file line will contain the variable name more than once, but I only need the variable name once. I tried:

```
$variable_names = @()
$samples = Get-Content C:<path to file>\code_clip.txt
foreach ($line in $samples) {$variable_names += (-$(\w+|\d+)){1} }
$variable_names.length
$variable_names
```

What is wrong with the RegEx?

Thanks

Edit:  This is a sample file's content:

```
if ($00_motion_type -ne 0) {Write-Output "00 motion_type: $00_motion_type"}
if ($ac_tex -ne 0) {Write-Output "ac-tex damaged: $ac_tex"}
if ($delta_bit -ne 0) {Write-Output "delta bit allocation strategy reserved: $delta_bit"}
if ($end_mismatch -ne 0) {Write-Output "end mismatch: $end_mismatch"}
if ($audio_block -ne 0) {Write-Output "error decoding the audio block: $audio_block"}
if ($decoding_stream -ne 0) {Write-Output "Error while decoding stream: $decoding_stream"}
if ($expacc -ne 0) {Write-Output "expacc: $expacc"}
if ($exponent -ne 0) {Write-Output "exponent: $exponent"}
if ($f_mb_incr -ne 0) {Write-Output "first mb_incr damaged: $f_mb_incr"}
if ($CRC_mismatch -ne 0) {Write-Output "frame CRC mismatch: $CRC_mismatch"}
if ($pic_cod_ext -ne 0) {Write-Output "ignoring pic cod ext: $pic_cod_ext"}
if ($seq_ext -ne 0) {Write-Output "ignoring seq_ext: $seq_ext"}
if ($GOP_START_CODE -ne 0) {Write-Output "ignoring GOP_START_CODE: $GOP_START_CODE"}
if ($incomplete_frame -ne 0) {Write-Output "incomplete frame: $incomplete_frame"}
if ($increasing_dts -ne 0) {Write-Output "increasing dts: $increasing_dts"}
if ($invalid_cbp -ne 0) {Write-Output "invalid cbp: $invalid_cbp"}
if ($coupling_range -ne 0) {Write-Output "invalid coupling range: $coupling_range"}
if ($frame_dimensions -ne 0) {Write-Output "Invalid frame dimensions: $frame_dimensions"}
if ($mb_type -ne 0) {Write-Output "invalid mb type: $mb_type"}
if ($matrix_damaged -ne 0) {Write-Output "matrix damaged: $matrix_damaged"}
if ($mb_incr -ne 0) {Write-Output "mb incr damaged: $mb_incr"}
if ($picture_start_code -ne 0) {Write-Output "Missing picture start code: $picture_start_code"}
if ($new_coupling_coordinates -ne 0) {Write-Output "new coupling coordinates: $new_coupling_coordinates"}
if ($new_coupling_strategy -ne 0) {Write-Output "new coupling strategy: $new_coupling_strategy"}
if ($overread -ne 0) {Write-Output "overread: $overread"}
if ($qscale -ne 0) {Write-Output "qscale == 0: $qscale"}
if ($sequence_header -ne 0) {Write-Output "sequence header damaged: $sequence_header"}
if ($previntra -ne 0) {Write-Output "skip with previntra: $previntra"}
if ($skipped_MB -ne 0) {Write-Output "skipped MB: $skipped_MB"}
if ($slice_below_image -ne 0) {Write-Output "slice below image: $slice_below_image"}
if ($slice_mismatch -ne 0) {Write-Output "slice mismatch: $slice_mismatch"}
if ($MVs_not_available -ne 0) {Write-Output "Warning MVs not available: $MVs_not_available"}
if ($othererror -ne 0) {Write-Output "Other error(s): $othererror"}
```

I am using this to select variable names that are known to be typed in correctly, and I want to append "=0" to each so as to copy and paste the whole list into code so it can be used to reset variables to 0.

Comment: Why are you not showing your input sample? Why are you trying to assign this? ```foreach ($line in $samples) {$variable_names += (-$(\w+|\d+)){1} }``` --- This is not a valid this based on what you say you want. It's just a string, ```$00incomplete_frame```, so,  just grab the string.

Comment: I added the file content currently being used.  Yes, they are text strings.

Comment: See my answer for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This produces the result I was looking for:

```
$variable_names = @()
$reset_variables = @()
$samples = Get-Content C:<path to file>\code_clip.txt
foreach ($line in $samples) {$test= $line -match '\$\w+'; $variable_names += $matches.values }
foreach ($line in $variable_names) {$reset_variables += $line + "=0;" }
$reset_variables.length
$reset_variables
```

Result:

```
33
$00_motion_type=0;
$ac_tex=0;
$delta_bit=0;
$end_mismatch=0;
$audio_block=0;
$decoding_stream=0;
$expacc=0;
$exponent=0;
$f_mb_incr=0;
$CRC_mismatch=0;
$pic_cod_ext=0;
$seq_ext=0;
$GOP_START_CODE=0;
$incomplete_frame=0;
$increasing_dts=0;
$invalid_cbp=0;
$coupling_range=0;
$frame_dimensions=0;
$mb_type=0;
$matrix_damaged=0;
$mb_incr=0;
$picture_start_code=0;
$new_coupling_coordinates=0;
$new_coupling_strategy=0;
$overread=0;
$qscale=0;
$sequence_header=0;
$previntra=0;
$skipped_MB=0;
$slice_below_image=0;
$slice_mismatch=0;
$MVs_not_available=0;
$othererror=0;
```

Since the variable names were known to be correct and working, I can use this to copy and paste into code to zero them out.

Actually, I'm using the below for horizontal output:

```
$variable_names = @()
$reset_variables = ""
$samples = Get-Content C:<path to file>\code_clip.txt
foreach ($line in $samples) {$test= $line -match '\$\w+'; $variable_names += $matches.values }
foreach ($line in $variable_names) {$reset_variables = $reset_variables + $line + '=0; ' }
$reset_variables
```

```
$00_motion_type=0; $ac_tex=0; $delta_bit=0; $end_mismatch=0; $audio_block=0; $decoding_stream=0; $expacc=0; $exponent=0; $f_mb_incr=0; $CRC_mismatch=0; $pic_cod_ext=0; $seq_ext=0; $GOP_START_CODE=0; $incomplete_frame=0; $increasing_dts=0; $invalid_cbp=0; $coupling_range=0; $frame_dimensions=0; $mb_type=0; $matrix_damaged=0; $mb_incr=0; $picture_start_code=0; $new_coupling_coordinates=0; $new_coupling_strategy=0; $overread=0; $qscale=0; $sequence_header=0; $previntra=0; $skipped_MB=0; $slice_below_image=0; $slice_mismatch=0; $MVs_not_available=0; $othererror=0;
```

Comment: Good to see you worked this out. If that solves your use case, be sure to accept it as your own answer. ***;-}***

Comment: Forgot to mention, thanks for the tip of escaping the $ symbol.

Comment: No worries glad it helped. Mea culpa for not getting back sooner, as what you have here was what I similarly worked up for you, but you got there already. ***;-}*** --- good work